# Can you sharpen scissors by cutting Aluminum foil?

Tags: consumer-products

I needed to sharpen a pair of scissors, so I did a quick Google search to learn the technique.  I was very surprised to find a number of sites suggesting that scissors can be sharpened by cutting a piece of aluminum foil.  It doesn't make any sense to me, and I didn't bother to try it.  But there were enough references that I'm curious whether anyone has ever actually tested the claim and formed a conclusion.  I found an assortment of comments from people saying it works or doesn't work, but nothing convincing either way.

For example, [*This Old House*](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/photos/0,,20513767_20994193,00.html) makes the claim.

> Fold a sheet of foil several times and cut through it with a pair of dull scissors to sharpen the blades.

[*Aluminum Foil to Sharpen Scissors*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqjFIwU_LUQ)
is a YouTube video illustrating the technique.

Comment: Searching and sandpaper supposedly works too, which makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Tanath, it sounds like you're describing [stropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razor_strop), which straightens out a folded-over cutting edge without removing material.  [Sharpening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knife_sharpening) removes material to create a new, sharper edge.

Comment: Yes. Regardless of what you call it, it makes it more effective, which I think is the intent.

Comment: I have no evidence for this, but intuitively it makes a lot of sense. Aluminium is harder than many steels, especially cheap steels likely to be found in scissors. A handy way to polish steel parts is to use wet aluminium foil, which degrades into a grinding agent when rubbed on something hard (I've used this technique myself, often). I don't know whether this would work for sharpening, but it ought to at least _polish_ the steel. Be interested to a properly sourced answer.

Comment: sharpening is done at an angle. this at most hones the scissors edge https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU2mbWwVSXU

Comment: @JohnDoucette "Aluminium is harder than many steels…" Really?  I always thought aluminium is *softer* than most types of steel.  Sure, there might be some exotic(?) aluminium alloys that are harder than the softest steels, but I doubt that's what is in aluminium foil.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been clearer. It's aluminium _oxide_ that is harder than most steels (Moh's hardness of 9). The oxide forms on the outside of aluminium foils and powders. See: http://www.reade.com/Particle_Briefings/mohs_hardness_abrasive_grit.html

Comment: There are two references but both seem miserable. I would say, close.

Comment: @h22 This Old House is notable.

Comment: Everything I've found is anecdotal with many of the more informed one saying that this will only work a few times before the shears are ruined.

Comment: My grandpa told me to cut fine sandpaper. I ever wondered if that works, as well.

Answer (score 9):

I could not find experimental evidence, but the majority of people on a sharpening forum seem to agree that it will **not work**.
https://www.bladeforums.com/threads/sharpening-scissors-with-aluminum-foil.847263/

Here it is discussed that dirt and rust may be removed which facilitates cutting, but it is **not sharpening** per se.
https://adventures99.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/is-it-true-sharpening-scissors-with-aluminum-foil/comment-page-1/

All high-quality scissor manufactures I looked up **do not list** aluminium foil for sharpening, this can be seen as weak evidence against the efficiency of it.

Comment: The same question has been asked at the Physics SE ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439238/75633)), and in [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/442478/75633) I add some considerations on the possibility that aluminum oxide film might be abrasive enough to do some sharpening (spoiler: probably not).